# could not get data by id using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm able to retrieve my data using command of mongo in terminal like `db.getCollection('catalog').find({user_id:"56703f1a2fc76861e6a8743e"})` but when I try in nodejs I got null.

My routes goes like this

```
var Catalog = require('../models/catalog');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else{
    Catalog.getAllCatalog('56703f1a2fc76861e6a8743e', function(catalog){
        console.log(catalog) //null
        res.render('catalog/index');
    });
  }
});
```

My models of catalog

```
var Catalog = module.exports = mongoose.model('catalog', catalogScheme);
module.exports.getAllCatalog = function(user_id, callback){
    Catalog.find({"user_id":user_id}, callback);
}
```

Any thought?

Comment: Are you sure that you configured your Mongoose schema so it uses the `catalog` collection? By default, it will use `catalogs` (plural) ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection)). Also, have you declared `user_id` in your schema to be a string? Perhaps you should include your schema in your question as well.

Comment: @robertklep there's no spelling error. here's my schema look like http://pastebin.com/B5kgZ0Dn. One more thing, mongoose.model('catalog') means your collection have to be named as `catalog` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as @chridam already pointed out in their answer, Node.js convention for callbacks is that they have (at least) two arguments: the first one is reserved to pass errors, and the second (and possibly any other) are for passing result data.

Second, Mongoose will, by default, take the model name (`catalog` in your case) and lowercase and pluralize it to determine the MongoDB collection name it will use. So your model `catalog` will use the collection named `catalogs` by default. This behaviour is documented [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).

Since your data is stored in a collection called `catalog` (singular), your queries don't yield any results. To fix this, you need to specify in the schema that Mongoose should use `catalog` as the collection:

```
var catalogScheme = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
}, { collection : 'catalog' });
```

**EDIT**: you can also disable name mangling entirely, which would Mongoose use the model name as the collection name:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('pluralization', false);

// create your schema/models from here...
```

Comment: then what does `mongoose.model('catalog', catalogScheme);` do? the first param? isn't that already means the name of my collection?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler no, that's the name of your _model_ (well, to be fair, the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) calls it _"the singular name of the collection your model is for"_, but subsequently states that _"Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name"_).

Comment: hmm seems like i have to change all of the collection name to have `s`.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler or change your schema so the singular version of the collection name will be used. Might be easier to do if your database already has (a lot of) data.

Comment: but if I have a collection call catagory, will mongoses automatically look for pural `catagories`?

Comment: I don't like someone force me in naming things. last confusion, the name of my model is useless isn't? when will i be using that again? I mean the first param of this `mongoose.model('catalog', catalogScheme);`

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler I just edited my answer, you may be able to turn off the name mangling completely. FWIW, the name of the model isn't entirely useless, because it provides you with an easy way to access the model class without having to import it. Also, it's still the basis for what Mongoose will use as collection name.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function only has one parameter, you need to have two arguments: the `err` object and the `result`. You could restructure your code in your else clause as:

```
Catalog.getAllCatalog('56703f1a2fc76861e6a8743e', function(err, catalog){
    if (err) { /* handle error here */ };
    console.log(catalog);
    res.render('catalog/index');
});
```

Comment: every callback is 2 param,is that how nodejs work? compulsory?

Comment: tried that but that's not the only problem problem. I got empty array but with command I'm getting something.